# Beautifulsoup decompose()

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get rid of `<script>` tags and the content inside the tag utilizing beatifulsoup. I went to the documentation and seems to be a really simple function to call. More information about the function is [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose). Here is the content of the html page that I have parsed so far...

```
<body class="pb-theme-normal pb-full-fluid">
    <div class="pub_300x250 pub_300x250m pub_728x90 text-ad textAd text_ad text_ads text-ads text-ad-links" id="wp-adb-c" style="width: 1px !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -10000px !important;
    top: -1000px !important;
    ">
</div>
<div id="pb-f-a">
</div>
    <div class="" id="pb-root">
    <script>
    (function(a){
        TWP=window.TWP||{};
        TWP.Features=TWP.Features||{};
        TWP.Features.Page=TWP.Features.Page||{};
        TWP.Features.Page.PostRecommends={};
        TWP.Features.Page.PostRecommends.url="https://recommendation-hybrid.wpdigital.net/hybrid/hybrid-filter/hybrid.json?callback\x3d?";
        TWP.Features.Page.PostRecommends.trackUrl="https://recommendation-hybrid.wpdigital.net/hybrid/hybrid-filter/tracker.json?callback\x3d?";
        TWP.Features.Page.PostRecommends.profileUrl="https://usersegment.wpdigital.net/usersegments";
        TWP.Features.Page.PostRecommends.canonicalUrl=""
    })(jQuery);

    </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Imagine you have some web content like that and you have that in a BeautifulSoup object called `soup_html`. If I run `soup_html.script.decompose()` and them call the object `soup_html` the script tags still there. How I can get rid of the `<script>` and the content inside those tags?

```
markup = 'The html above'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
html_body = soup.body

soup.script.decompose()

html_body
```

Comment: Paste the actual code you are running. When I test the steps you've described everything is alright. **EDIT** Also, you are missing a closing `div`, but that's no problem for BS

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> `soup.script.decompose()`

This would remove a *single script element* from the "Soup" only. Instead, I think you meant to decompose all of them:

```
for script in soup("script"):
    script.decompose()
```

Comment: For some reason the `decompose()` stop working. Now I have `script` code in my `.txt` files. I went to the documentation and the instructions are pretty much the same as before.

Comment: ```# Removing JS and CSS
    for script in soup('script', 'style'):
        script.decompose()
        with open(my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w') as webpage_out:
        webpage_out.write(soup.get_text())
        print('The file ' + my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt ' + 'has been created successfully.')
        count += 1
    except:
            pass```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the simplest, yet a very effective method to get rid of everything useless. I am benefiting from this method for long enough now. :)

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on the answer provided by alecxe, here is a full script for anyone's reference:

```
selects = soup.findAll('select')
for match in selects:
    match.decompose()
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the issue with the following code...

```
scripts = soup.findAll(['script', 'style'])
    for match in scripts:
        match.decompose()
        file_content = soup.get_text()
        # Striping 'ascii' code
        content = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', r' ', file_content)
    # Creating 'txt' files
    with open(my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w+') as webpage_out:
        webpage_out.write(content)
        print('The file ' + my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt ' + 'has been created successfully.')
        count += 1
```

The error was that the `with open(...` was part or the `for match...`

Code that **did not** work...

```
scripts = soup.findAll(['script', 'style'])
    for match in scripts:
        match.decompose()
        file_content = soup.get_text()
        # Striping 'ascii' code
        content = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', r' ', file_content)
        # Creating 'txt' files
        with open(my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w+') as webpage_out:
            webpage_out.write(content)
            print('The file ' + my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt ' + 'has been created successfully.')
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The soup.script.decompose() would only remove it from the soup variable... not the html_body variable. you would have to remove it from the html_body variable as well. (I think.)