# How to discard certain tag and continue with the rest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to scrape some text out of some html elements. When I execute my script, it gives me all the text available in it. I do not wish to get the text within `p` tag. Few days back when i went through `BeautifulSoup` documentation and I found a method `.decompose()`. Although i didn't understand what that does, i thought i might give this a try. However, upon execution, i get an error.

This is the script:

```
html_elem ='''    
<div class="track">
    <p id="core">
        pop singer<span class="lnkcat"> intranet </span>
    </p>
    <p id="crude">
        songs<span class="lnkitm"> online </span>
    </p>
    <p id="evergreen">
        instrumental<span class="lnkapt"> hotline </span>
    </p>
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">track one</a>
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">track two</a>
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">track three</a>
</div>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_elem, "lxml")
item = soup.find_all(class_="track")
# item.p.decompose()
for elem in item:
    print(elem.text.strip())
```

I get this error when I uncomment the line containing `.decompose()` and run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Social.py", line 28, in <module>
    item.p.decompose()
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'p'
```

Btw, only using `.find_all("a")`, I could have got the desired data but i wish to know/learn even if i select the class `track` I will only get the text within `a` tag excluding the text within `p` tag.

Comment: I think the error is because find_all() returns a list. item[0].p.decompose() should solve that.

Comment: You are almost there @Swakeert Jain. Now it discards the first `p` tag. How about the rest two `p` tags? Thanks a lot for the catch.

Comment: for p in item[0]("p"): p.decompose()
this should do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904439/5561737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_elem, "lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_="track"):
    [elem.extract() for elem in soup('p')]
    print(item.text.strip())
```

It now gives me the below results:

```
track one
track two
track three
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Swakeert Jain mentioned you can't use `.decompose()` on the whole code. You can however a for loop to remove them 1 by 1.

```
html_elem ='''    
<div class="track">
    <p id="core">
        pop singer<span class="lnkcat"> intranet </span>
    </p>
    <p id="crude">
        songs<span class="lnkitm"> online </span>
    </p>
    <p id="evergreen">
        instrumental<span class="lnkapt"> hotline </span>
    </p>
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">track one</a>
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">track two</a>
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">track three</a>
</div>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_elem, "lxml")
item = soup.find_all(class_="track")
item[0].p.decompose() 
# decomposed by the index or loop through with a for loop and decompose each

for elem in item:
    print(elem)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Elvir Muslic. The problem is: it is still discarding the first `p` tag among the three. Not the rest two.

Comment: As I said in my comment above the code you can discard every `p` within the code with a for a loop.

Comment: I tried with for loop to achieve that but found no improvement. How that loop be that you recommended? You don't need to update your answer. Just paste here the loop. Btw, what i tried is : `for link in item:link.p.decompose()`.