# How do i get the text inside a class while ignoring the text of the next class that is inside

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text inside the class="hardfact" but is also getting the text of the class="hardfactlabel color_f_03" because this class is inside hardfact.

.text.strip() get the text of both class because they are nested.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests
import lxml

my_url = 'https://www.immowelt.de/expose/2QC5D4A?npv=52'

page = requests.get(my_url)
ct = soup(page.text, 'lxml')

specs = ct.find('div', class_="hardfacts clear").findAll('div', class_="hardfact")
for items in specs:
    e = items.text.strip()
    print(e)
```

I'm getting this

82.500 €

```
                                    Kaufpreis
```

47 m²

```
                                    Wohnfläche (ca.)
```

1

```
                                    Zimmer
```

and i want this

82.500 €

47 m²

1

Comment: Probably some kind of decompose operation on that unwanted class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885359/beautifulsoup-decompose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the html content you are trying to crawl:

```
<div class="hardfact ">
  <strong>82.500 €&nbsp;</strong>                                    
  <div class="hardfactlabel color_f_03">
    Kaufpreis      
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hardfact ">
  47 m²                                    
  <div class="hardfactlabel color_f_03">
    Wohnfläche (ca.)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hardfact rooms">
  1                                    
  <div class="hardfactlabel color_f_03">
    Zimmer
  </div>
</div>
```

What you want to achieve is to remove the div tags within, so you can just decompose the div:

```
for items in specs:
  items.div.decompose()
  e = items.text.strip()
print(e)
```

If your first "hardfact" class doesn't contain the "strong" tag, you can just find the first element like so

```
e = items.find().text.strip()
```

but we can't do this so you have to decompose the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripped strings. You probably want to add a condition to ensure at least length of 3 before attempting to slice list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.immowelt.de/expose/2QC5D4A?npv=52')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
items = soup.select('.hardfact')[:3]

for item in items:
    strings = [string for string in item.stripped_strings]
    print(strings[0])
```